# Cut character string every two commas

Tags: python, string, list, split

I would like to separate my string every both commas but I can not, can you help me.
This is what I want: `['nb1,nb2','nb3,nb4','nb5,nb6']`

***Here is what I did :***

```
a= 'nb1,nb2,nb3,nb4,nb5,nb6'
compteur=0
for i in a:
    if i==',' :
        compteur+=1
        if compteur%2==0:
           print compteur
           test = a.split(',', compteur%2==0 )
print a
print test
```

***The result:***

```
2
4
nb1,nb2,nb3,nb4,nb5,nb6
['nb1', 'nb2,nb3,nb4,nb5,nb6']
```

Thanks you by advances for you answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix could be to simply first separate the elements by commas and **then join the elements by two together again**. Like:

```
sub_result = a.split(',')
result = [','.join(sub_result[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(sub_result),2)]
```

This gives:

```
>>> result
['nb1,nb2', 'nb3,nb4', 'nb5,nb6']
```

This will also work if the number of elements is odd. For example:

```
>>> a = 'nb1,nb2,nb3,nb4,nb5,nb6,nb7'
>>> sub_result = a.split(',')
>>> result = [','.join(sub_result[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(sub_result),2)]
>>> result
['nb1,nb2', 'nb3,nb4', 'nb5,nb6', 'nb7']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `regex`

```
In [12]: re.findall(r'([\w]+,[\w]+)', 'nb1,nb2,nb3,nb4,nb5,nb6')
Out[12]: ['nb1,nb2', 'nb3,nb4', 'nb5,nb6']
```

Answer (score 1):

You use a zip operation of the list with itself to create pairs:

```
a = 'nb1,nb2,nb3,nb4,nb5,nb6'
parts = a.split(',')
# parts = ['nb1', 'nb2', 'nb3', 'nb4', 'nb5', 'nb6']
pairs = list(zip(parts, parts[1:]))
# pairs = [('nb1', 'nb2'), ('nb2', 'nb3'), ('nb3', 'nb4'), ('nb4', 'nb5'), ('nb5', 'nb6')]
```

Now you can simply join **every other** pair again for your output:

```
list(map(','.join, pairs[::2]))
# ['nb1,nb2', 'nb3,nb4', 'nb5,nb6']
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by comma first, then apply the common idiom to partition an interable into sub-sequences of length n (where n is 2 in your case) with `zip`.

```
>>> s = 'nb1,nb2,nb3,nb4,nb5,nb6'
>>> [','.join(x) for x in zip(*[iter(s.split(','))]*2)]
['nb1,nb2', 'nb3,nb4', 'nb5,nb6']
```